# pwm after constant current switching driver

Tags: led, pwm

I have searched, but cant find an answer for my specific setup. I have a Xl4015 switching contant current source for my 10w LED set at 1000mA. I would like to add a pwm dimming circuit to switch a mosfet on the led ground. I am using an arduino to create the pwm signal that connects to the mosfet gate. It does dimm, but I do not have an oscilloscope and cant tell if there are any voltage or current spikes each time the led turns on and off.

Will pwm cause any current spikes in this case? Or could it damage the xl4015 circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XL Semi XL4015 5A 180KHz 36V Buck DC to DC Converter](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL4015%20datasheet.pdf) does not have a PWM (or Enable) control input.

[image]

It is very common to add an external MOSFET to a converter chip with an internal MOSFET.  You should be fine.

You would add your MOSFET to the output of the SW pin.

[image]

---

I think it would be easier to build this [Diode Inc AL8862](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8862.pdf) circuit than to retrofit the above circuit. The CTRL pin is your PWM input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking into using a different controller chip with a pwm pin. But that will be in the future. Since I already have these cc controllers.