# Adding PWM function to a XL Semi XL4015 5 A 180 kHz 36 V buck DC to DC converter to create a NUBM44 laser driver board

Tags: power-supply, pwm, laser-diode, cnc, laser-driver

I am asking this question just to make sure I haven't missed anything important because I am at best a novice when it comes to electrical engineering. What I am trying to do is build a laser driver board for a Nichia NUBM44 laser diode from parts that I have on hand, so my question is simply "Will my plan work or have I missed something?"

**Summary**

In order to create the laser driver board I was planning to add a IRFZ44N MOSFET to the negative output terminal of a XL4015 5 A 180 kHz 36 V buck DC to DC converter module since this module allows the ability to independently adjust the voltage and current via potentiometers.

The gate pin on the MOSFET will be connected to a STM32F103C8 (Blue pill) micro controller.

I plan to directly connect the laser diode to the output terminal of the buck DC to DC converter module and run this laser diode at 4.5 V and 4 A as per the datasheet (listed below).

**More Details / Context**

I am replacing the extruders with a laser diode on an old Makerbot Replicator 2x 3D Printer and wanted to upgrade the laser diode while I am at it.

Instead of buying a new laser driver board I thought I could just add PWM control to an existing power supply module that I had laying around.

I have looked at this question on this site:

[pwm after constant current switching driver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396097/pwm-after-constant-current-switching-driver)

and it seems that what I am doing is not groundbreaking at all but I wanted double check because the laser diode is not exactly cheap and I did not want to hurt myself or destroy the laser diode with a basic mistake.

**Diagram**

[image: Component Diagram]

**Resources**

1. [Nichia NUBM44 Laser Diode Datasheet](https://live-lasersystems.net/d/files/datenblatt_nubm44.pdf)
2. [XL4015 5A 180KHz 36V Buck DC to DC Converter module details](https://ssrobotics.in/product/xl4015-5a-step-down-buck-converter-cc-cv-charging-board-adjustable-lithium-battery-module-dc-dc/)
3. [IRFZ44N MOSFET datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/68619/IRF/IRFZ44N.html)

Please let me know if any sections need further explanation.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! You need your constant current limitation to clamp immediately when your PWM turns on. Those DC-DC converters have a large output capacitor so I suspect you will burn out your laser on the first or second pulse. You need a CC regulator with PWM input. Perhaps you can set your Vout very close to your Vf of your laser, but I wouldn't see it as a good long-term solution.

Comment: Would there be a way to measure with a multi meter, if the constant current limitation clamps immediately?

Comment: If it has some very good max hold function, otherwise you need an oscilloscope. But that won't solve the issue. I recommend you to look for a dedicated CC controller with PWM/EN input. There are plenty available for LEDs, even at 4 A, or use several in parallel if you can only find smaller ones.

Comment: Ok, my multi meter does have that function, so ill check if that issue exists. The DC-DC module is described with the following features :
"-> CC CV module
-> Low ripple
-> When the module charges a battery, it first use constant current to protect the battery. "

So there is a chance that this module might have a solution to the issue you mentioned. If not ill look for a more suitable laser driver board. Either way thanks for your help.

Comment: Best case yes, but they are built to a price and having overshoot on connection (or via external MOSFET, same thing) would require CC limitation after the output capacitor, adding cost. I would recommend you to use your DC-DC to provide an intermediate voltage to slightly above Vf (due to dropout) and have a linear regulator with PWM input to do the actual CC regulation. Also, you will need a scope to verify this in the end anyway. DMM is good for DC and 50/60 Hz AC. For everything else, you need a scope.

Comment: @CameronA, it's interesting to know what solution you have implemented in the end for this project.